# How many kinds of criterion to measure which feature distinguish the label better?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I have a data set like this:

```
label feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4 ...
0     value11   value21   value31
1     value12   value22   ...
4     value13   value23   ...
2     value14   value24   ...
1     value15   value25   ...
3     value16   value26   ...
...
```

- The value of `label` may be `{0,1,2,3,4}`
- `feature1` ranges from `0` to `10000`
- `feature2` ranges from `-4` to `3`
- and so on

For `feature1` and `feature2`, I want to check which feature can distinguish the label better, how many ways to make it?

I have thought of the following plans:

- check the pearson correlation between label and feature
- check the variance of `feature1` and `feature2`? But they have different range.
- simultaneously use `feature1` and `feature2` to split a decision tree and check which feature has larger information gain.
- do a linear regression using `feature1` and `feature2` and check the coefficient?
- plot the distribution plot of `feature1` and `feature2` but without the information of label

I want to know which method of the following is solid enough? Are there any other better methods? Which method is the best? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A very common approach is to use a cross validation set and perform "model selection",measuring using  performance metrics like: precision ,recall and f1 score. Your workflow would be(in pseudocode,not real code):

- list of models to evaluate = you define multiple model candidates, for example
  one features,two features, polynomial features .
- for every model "m" on you defined to evaluate

  - Train the model "m" on your train dataset
  - Obtain the performance metrics using cross validation set
  - Select your optimal model based on your perfomance metrics(obtained from the cross validation set)

This a very common a powerful approach . You can find more info on Andrew Ng. videos on this subject on youtube